# Creating multiple contracts or Single contract with struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain

I would like to understand which of the following patterns is better.

Say my use case is to have two types of users in my platform buyer and seller for a product, with regard to my architecture Im left with two options.

1. To have one contract which would have a struct defination of types of Users(Buyer/Seller) and Product.
2. To have dedicated contract for each module. - Have noticed this in git projects

I belive the product can be achived with both ways, However I would like to understand which approach is better in efficently coding using Blockchain.

Comment: This really comes down to style. Doing it in one contract is more efficient, and my personal choice, but contracts only cause a little bit of inefficiency and can make the code more readable, modular, and testable.

Comment: Thank's I get that, need one clarity is it true that having one contract would cost less over multiple contracts? cause more contract would require multiple operations.

Comment: Yes, having one contract will cost less than having multiple. I personally find it easier to reason about one contract, as well

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8615/child-contract-vs-struct?newreg=9940955131d740a1a85cef648b771ef3

Answer (score 5):

I think it comes down to more of your goals.  One contract is easier/more efficient by far, especially for finding everything (and is cheaper), but at the same time it's more centralized.  For instance if you are storing loads of Eth in the contract, have very complex code, and want lots of users to interact with it, a lot of value in one contract is not necessarily the best idea.  Also from a control/regulatory standpoint, having multiple contracts with distributed ownership (i.e. users own their own contract) can be a benefit.

Like hurb said though, this person gave some good reasons:
[Child contract vs struct](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8615/child-contract-vs-struct?newreg=9940955131d740a1a85cef648b771ef3)

Comment: This is a fair point, but note that if there's a bug that's replicated over different contracts then it makes no difference.