# Is this type of Dapp reasonable to be built on Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, gas-price

I'm currently doing some tests with Solidity programming language and EVM.
I want to create application where people could make a personal accounts and make some business logic then.
But I'm afraid of creating account **gas price**. 
Now I have very simple Account contract:

```
contract Account {
    string name;
    string secName;
    uint balance;

    function Account(string name, string secName) {
        name = name;
        secName = secName;
        balance = 1;
    }
}
```

Also I have function to create new account in other Manager contract

```
function createAccount(string name, string secName) isCreator {
        Account account = new Account(name, secName);
        accounts.push(account);
    }
```

Calling this function cost **127909** gas and now It's around **0.14$** (**5 gwei for gas**). Seems to be a little bit expensive for creating account with only two text fields.

So the questions is: probably ethereum blockchain is not good solution for Dapp like that or It's possible to decrease amount of gas for creating new account transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a separate contract for each account is probably overkill. Each new account will cost gas for the (identical!) code of the new contract, plus the smaller cost of a transaction. Ethereum may be meant for this, but not done in this way.

You may be able to use structs for the same purpose. For example:

```
struct Account {
        string name;
        string secName;
        uint balance;
}

Account[] accounts;

function createAccount(string name, string secName) isCreator {
    accounts.push(Account(name, secName, 1));
}
```

This will likely provide whatever you need, much easier and simpler. You can also look into [libraries](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries).

See [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8615/child-contract-vs-struct) for my answer elsewhere on this kind of subject.